# Changing my model's ID to a UUID corrupted Paperclip file paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, paperclip

I have a model called SpacePhoto. SpacePhoto `has_attached_file :photo` through Paperclip.

SpacePhoto used to have a integer ID, but I recently changed it to a UUID, with the following migration:

```
class ChangePhotoPrimaryKeyType < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :space_photos, :uuid, :uuid, default: "uuid_generate_v4()", null: false

    change_table :space_photos do |t|
      t.remove :id
      t.rename :uuid, :id
    end

    execute "ALTER TABLE space_photos ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);"
  end
end
```

To get the url, I would do `space_photo.photo.url`, but now that no longer gives me the correct url. For example, before running that migration, I would get the url https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/instally.beta/space_photos/photos/000/000/071/original/avatar.jpg?1478889772 . Now, I get https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/instally.beta/space_photos/photos/086/a71/a9-/original/avatar.jpg?1479167261

The difference is the 3 groups of 3 characters in the middle of the URL, but I don't know enough about Paperclip internals to figure out where those are coming from.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are having is a result of the Paperclip url for attachments using the `:id_partition` interpolation, which splits the `id` into 3 character split path form for the first 9 characters.

I suspect this is because you haven't supplied a url option and Paperclip is using the default of:

```
/system/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename
```

To override this you need to specify the `url` option and replace `:id_partition` with the `:id` interpolation instead. In your model that has the attachment change the `has_attached_file` declaration to:

```
has_attached_file :photo,
                    url: '/system/:class/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename'
```